# How to download a PDF file from Google Sheet with specific margins and page breaks?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I see some ways to generate PDF from google sheets. But can not find how to set page settings like hiding gridlines, set margins, page breaks etc.
When I choice download as PDF from file menu I can do this.
So is there some method to get access to page settings with script?

[image]

My sheet contains charts and picture. I'm looking for method which not ignoring media content

Answer (score 3):

### The easiest way to convert an Google Spreadsheet to pdf specifying different parameters is with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

It allows you to specify different printing options by adding them to the url,among others the margins and gridlines.

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/export?";

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                                   // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=true'                                // orientation, false for landscape
  +'&top_margin=0.50'
  +'&bottom_margin=0.50' 
  +'&left_margin=0.50' 
  +'&right_margin=0.50'
  + '&gridlines=false' 
  // other parameters if you need
  /*
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'                       // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'             // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false'                               // hide page numbers 
  + '&fzr=false'                                     // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                                         // the sheet's Id
  */

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, 
   {
    headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    },
    muteHttpExceptions:true
  });
  DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob().setName("myPdf"));
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a way to set page breaks, but people are using [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358903/is-it-possible-to-add-page-breaks-into-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script/60095870#60095870).